# Navbar show hide is not working after login,Angular

Tags: angular

my navbar is inside my app.component.html:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" *ngIf="toShow">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="assets/leitwind_logo.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
     
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-dashboard">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/app-events">EventLog</a>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="Logout()">Exit </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in my app.component.ts:

```
     token: string;
     toShow:boolean=false;

     ngOnInit(){
     if (sessionStorage.getItem('token')){
          this.toShow=true;
                                         }
          else
              {
          this.toShow=false;
              }
            }
        Logout(){
          sessionStorage.removeItem("token");

               }
```

when I login everything is shown but NavBar, even if I put a condition there, any idea?

Comment: what `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` returns?

Comment: @deerawan it was localStorage instead of sessionStorage and it was returning the token then i was told the localStorage is not safe so change to sessionStorage

Comment: hmm, it should work if the returned value exist. Have you tried to put `{{ toShow }}` in the template just to check what the value is?

Comment: @deerawan im going to test it and will update you in short

Comment: @deerawan it returns Object which my token is inside!

Comment: The value of `{{ toShow }}` should be either true or false, not an object.

Comment: @deerawan what's the alternative if I don't want to use this approach?

Comment: the code looks good to me but interesting that it doesn't show the navbar. Could you remove all the code in `ngOnInit` related to `toShow` and try to assign `toShow: boolean = true` in its first initialization and check the navbar again?

Comment: Please post the login code, what you've posted is not enough to determine the problem. Here you only check `sessionStorage` in `ngOnInit`. You have to do this again after login (or set `toShow = true;`).